# How to determine if an index is within a group within a list using JS (similar to the css nth selector)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to determine if a **INDEX** is the **SECOND** item in a **GROUP** of 11 in a list of an undetermined list. In css I can do this using the nth selector:

```
:nth-child(11n + 2)
```

The list is a single array so the groups is just a counter that I use.

```
listLength = X
groupLength = 11
indexCheck = 2
selectedIndex = Y
```

I dont want to do this with a **LOOP** as I am sure there is a better way to determine the group position and the selected index position.

It is NOT an array of arrays. Its a single array of items that for every 11 I want to determine is the index I have is the 2nd in that 11. I need to do this so I can apply some logic to the item that must be unique to that item in that count/group.

EXAMPLE:

2 is the 2nd item in the first 11 count/group

13 is the 2nd item in the second 11 count/group

24 is the 2nd item in the third 11 count/group

Below is an to show that is a single array format.

```
[
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
]
```

I have the index of the item in the array I just need to calculate its position after checking the count as well.

Comment: Your terminology is slightly confusing. Do you have an array of arrays? What is the structure of the object/array you are wanting to traverse and search?

Comment: Do you need to access or find any specific array element? Or do you just need to perform some sort of mathematical validation of the given values? Really really unclear what you actually want here, so please edit the question and supply an actual example of what input data you have, and what specific result you expect based on that.

Comment: I updated the question with an example of what I am trying to get from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this and say whether its okay for you

```
    data = [
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ,21,22,23,24
      ]
      groupLength = 11
      indexCheck = 17

   const len = this.data.length;// get the length of the array
    const getInd = this.data.indexOf(this.indexCheck) + 1; // get the index of the given value 
    if(getInd == 0){
      // value is not present just return
      console.log('this index is not present in the array')
      return;
    }
    //From the index divide by grouplength and round by math ceil method. In item variable holds how much group can be splitted inside data array if we given 13 then it will take 2 groups
    const item = Math.ceil(getInd / this.groupLength);
    const groupIndex = this.groupLength * item;
    // itemIndex holds the in which index the value is present in array by splitting in to groups
    let itemIndex = null
    if(groupIndex == this.groupLength){
      itemIndex = getInd
    }else{
      itemIndex = getInd - (groupIndex - this.groupLength)
    }

    console.log(`${this.indexCheck} is the ${itemIndex} item in the ${this.groupLength} count/group `)
```

Pls check the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5gft2f?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)